# How to control the Text with more characters(both alphabets and numeric values) in an td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

Is any option to control the text which is in `<td>`

I am using this css style:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
```

Without any text in td it is looking good but when there is a text by using the above css the UI alignment is getting disturbed.

[image]

[image]

See here in second image the alignment at QR tag td is disturbed completely.

Even if there are more no.of characters are there the alignment shouldnot be disturbed .

please help me out with this issue.

Comment: you should post your table css to understand along with the html!! If fiddle is created then it would be great!!

Comment: Do you mean the height of the row? Do you want the height of each cell to only fit one line of text?

Comment: Exactly but not in the one line.

Comment: Please share some additional HTML/CSS, and/or create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The issue could be that the cells' width is not defined and it changes when content is added, but without any code, it's impossible to know

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want the row to have a fixed height so that only one line of text to be visible.

```
 width: 250px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: NO i dont want to hidden the text i need to show the entire text in multiple lines in that particular <td>